# Magento 1 : i added custom attribute in product but when get it in collection it print unknown column

Tags: sorting, magento, attributes, product

i want to sort my collection by custom attribute 
i added attribute called **sort** to sort by that attribute
when get collection and sort with that attribute not get in collection as unknown called
i use to sort
$_productCollection->setOrder('sort', 'desc');
or
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSort('sort', 'desc');

**Note**
when i use https://website/test.php as test file
the same code and it working well but inside magento it unknown column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$_productCollection->addFieldToFilter('sort')
    ->setOrder('desc');
```

Comment: the problem was in system->configuration->catalog->frontend set no to flat product and flush cache